# SQLServerException: 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to create table and two views using JDBC (code is shown below).  While executing first `CREATE VIEW` query, I get the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
```

I execute each command separately, every approach throws that exception. Things I've tried:

- running with `autoCommit(true)`
- `commit`ing after each `execute(sql)`
- running each query as a single batch (`stmt.addBatch(sql); stmt.executeBatch();`)
- running each query with a new `Statement` (`conn.createStatement()`)

Is there any other method I could try?

#### Sample code

```
CREATE TABLE source (
    a int  NOT NULL,
    b int  NOT NULL,
    c int  NOT NULL,
    d int  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT source_pk PRIMARY KEY  (a)
);

CREATE VIEW "delete"
AS
SELECT a, b FROM source;

CREATE VIEW migrate
AS
SELECT c, d FROM source;
```

Comment: Just a silly idea: I think that you have to clear your statements before you use `stmt.addBatch(sql)`. If this does not help you should try to use the SQL Server Profiler to monitor the incoming statements.

Comment: @Shnugo: Tried `clearBatch()` - it does not work.

Comment: @Kikert, I did not see your *running each query with a new Statement* at the first sight... This should suffice... At the moment you think you are executing the `CREATE VIEW` there seems to be another command in the queue which is executed before. Try to monitor this action...

Comment: Please show the code as you are executing it. Note that you should execute one statement at a time, not multiple statements in one go.

Answer (score 3):

Try to put a GO keyword after your first Create view like

```
CREATE TABLE source (
    a int  NOT NULL,
    b int  NOT NULL,
    c int  NOT NULL,
    d int  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT source_pk PRIMARY KEY  (a)
);
GO
CREATE VIEW "delete"
AS
SELECT a, b FROM source;
GO

CREATE VIEW migrate
AS
SELECT c, d FROM source;
```

**On a side note:** Try to avoid naming your tables which are keywords.

In JDBC you can do like

```
if not exists(select 1 from sys.tables where name='SomeDelete')
begin
    exec('CREATE VIEW "SomeDelete" AS SELECT a, b FROM source;');
end
if not exists(select 1 from sys.tables where name='migrate')
begin
    exec('CREATE VIEW migrate AS SELECT c, d FROM source;');
end
```

Comment: `GO` is not a valid SQL statement and will generate an error when sent through JDBC (it's only used by e.g. SQL Server Management Studio)

Comment: GO is not supported in JDBC driver: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx When tried, it throws SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi regarding naming: that SQL is just a sample.